# docker ps shows different ports than nmap

Tags: docker, ports, nmap

`docker ps` says there are three ports forwarded:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                      NAMES
06584d4ad44e        quay.io/coreos/etcd:v3.1.8   "etcd -name etcd01..."   2 days ago          Up 3 minutes        0.0.0.0:2379-2380->2379-2380/tcp, 0.0.0.0:4001->4001/tcp   etcd01
```

But `nmap -sT 127.0.0.1` can only find the `4001`:

```
Starting Nmap 7.40 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-06-13 00:06 CEST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.0011s latency).
Not shown: 969 closed ports, 30 filtered ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
4001/tcp open  newoak
```

How comes? Can I verify if the ports are there in another way?

Comment: Did you try `netstat -tunlp` (ubuntu) | `netstat -avn` (mac)?

Comment: Running `sudo`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**nmap** doesn't scan all ports by default.

As you can see, it only scanned 1000 ports: 969 (closed) + 30 (filtered) + 1 (open).

To really scan *all* ports, you should specify use the `-p` option like this: `-p1-65535`.  It may take a while, though...  Customize the options to make it faster.  You need to run as root for TCP SYN scan.  The default TCP Connect is slower.

Do not use **nmap** for knowing which ports are opened when you're in the host.  Use either **netstat** (deprecated) as in `netstat -tunlp` or **ss** (which accepts most of the same options as **netstat**): `ss -tunlp`.  The options are nmemonic:

> -t for TCP
>
> -u for UDP
>
> -n for numeric
>
> -l for listening ports
>
> -p for PID's